# MySQL export table with indexes set to DEFAULT

Tags: mysql

Stacker's

I wish to export a large mySql table data but not keep the indexes and replace them with DEFAULT. So that when I import it into a test environment, I don't override the current indexes for that table.

So basically each row current index value is replaced by DEFAULT, so the INSERT uses the auto increment to get a new index:

```
INSERT INTO `user_history` (`n`, `user_uid`, `history_id`, `type`, `meta_uid`, `modified`) VALUES
(DEFAULT, '3abc3eaf0b3e', 1, 'color', '1', '2015-07-29 08:01:52'),
(DEFAULT, '3abc3eaf0b3e', 1, 'size', '2', '2015-07-29 08:01:52');
```

This is just an example. I cannot simply manually edit the file as it is huge.

10mil +1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

```
SELECT NULL, `user_uid`, `history_id`, `type`, `meta_uid`, `modified`
FROM `user_history`
INTO OUTFILE '<file name here>.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

By default, the file will be output into you data directory unless you explicitly give MySQL a path when naming the file.

To load the file through the command line:

```
mysql -u <user> -p <database for new table> -e "LOAD DATA INFILE '<file name>.csv'
          INSERT INTO TABLE `user_history`
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
          ENCLOSED BY '\"'
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Nathan, great solution.